# Find all solutions to $x^2+54=y^3$ over the integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Find all solutions to $x^2+54=y^3$ over the integers. Hint: the ideal class group order of $\mathcal{O}_{-6}$, $h_{\sqrt{-6}}=2$.

$$\\$$
First we note that if $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$, then $R=\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$, and by some theorem, since $-6\equiv2 \pmod4$, then the ideal $(2)_R$ ramifies into $\mathfrak{p}_2^2$, where $\mathfrak{p}_2=(2,\sqrt{-6})_R$, which cannot be a principal ideal since there is no solution to $a^2+6b^2=2$ over the integers. Hence the class group $Cl(R)=\{e,[\mathfrak{p}_2]\}$, since its order is 2.

We can factorise so that if $\alpha =x+3\sqrt{-6}$, then $\alpha\tilde{\alpha}=y^3$.

Now, note that $2\nmid x$ (otherwise $2|y\Rightarrow 4|54=2\cdot3^3$, contradiction), so $2\nmid y$.

This means that $(y)_R^3\sim e $, since otherwise we would have $\mathfrak{p}_2|(y)_R^3\Rightarrow \mathfrak{p}_2^2|(y)_R^3$ which we cannot have by the above. Hence $(\alpha\tilde\alpha)_R\sim (y)_R^3\sim e$. This in turn implies that in the maximal ideal decomposition of $(\alpha)_R$, we cannot have a factor of $\mathfrak{p}_2$, and so $(\alpha)_R\sim(\tilde\alpha)_R\sim e$. Then we can write $(\alpha)_R=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{q}_i^{r_i}$ for $\mathfrak{q}_i\nsim\mathfrak{p}_2$ maximal ideals. We can now deduce that $3|r_i\;\; \forall i$, so that we can write $(\beta)_R=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{q}_i^{r_i/3}$ with $(\beta)^3_R=(\alpha)_R$.

As both are principal ideals, we can write $\beta^3=\alpha=x+3\sqrt{-6}$ for some $a+b\sqrt{-6}=\beta\in R$. Solving this equation by comparing coefficients we get that: $\beta^3=a(a^2-18b^2)+3b(a^2-2b^2)\sqrt{-6}=x+3\sqrt{-6}\Rightarrow b(a^2-2b^2)=3$, and we get that the only solution is $b=-1,a=\pm 1\Rightarrow x=\pm17\Rightarrow y=7$.

So $(\pm 17,7)$ are all the solutions.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Does $x = 17$, $y = 7$ count as a solution?

Comment: Yes, but I need to find all of them

Comment: I was just checking you had copied the equation correctly.

Comment: what is the source of the problem?

Comment: oh, well. very similar to Theorem 14.2.3 in Alaca and Williams, the big difference being that $54$ is not squarefree. So, plow through that proof with your $x \pm 3 \sqrt {-6}$

Comment: I added to my own attempt at solution. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: The source of the problem is one of the problem sheets from my algebraic number theory class, I can't really give you more than that.

Comment: By simple test of some numbers we can find the solutions. x and y are both odd or even. y^3 must be greater than 54, say the third power of 5 , 7, 9,  . Taking 7 we get x^2=7^3-54=289=17^2. So x=±17. The proof by op that these are only solutions is great .

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of Mordell's elliptic curves $y^2=x^3+k$, here with $k=-54$. Keith Conrad has a [note](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf), where he explains how to find all integral solutions in the cases, where algebraic number theory can be applied. This is in section $3$, compare with Theorem $3.3$, $3.4$, Example $3.7$, $3.8$.